# Why does listFiles on Android only list files with certain extensions?

Tags: java, android

On my Android device, I have multiple files located in my 'external storage' directory, but not all files are listed when using 'listFiles' in my Java Andoid app. Only files with certain extensions are listed. I want to list all files.

Example: When I have two files named 'Testfile1.mp4' and 'Testfile2.txt', then only 'Testfile1.mp4' is listed. If I rename 'Testfile2.txt' to 'Testfile2.mp4', then both files are listed, but I want to list all files without renaming.

Here is the code I use:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] files = path.listFiles(file -> !file.isDirectory());
```

In 'AndroidManifest.xml', I have:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and in my app, the permissions are confirmed by the user of the app.
I tried with Android Studio, with an empty Activity, with 'minSdkVersion' set to 28 and 'compileSdkVersion' and 'targetSdkVersion' set to 30.

Comment: Android version of used device(s)?

Comment: The device uses Android 11.

Comment: And who put those files in root of external storage.? And which app do you use to change file names?

Comment: The files were uploaded with 'Device File Explorer' in Android Studio. The file names were changed with 'OnePlus' file manager.

Comment: A normal app on an Android 11 device only sees its own files or a bunch of media files. That's what you encounter.